Finite generation and finite presentation over a truncated valuation ring: is there an easier proof?
Let $K^+$ be a valuation ring which is $\pi$-adically complete for some pseudouniformizer $\pi$.
Nagata 053E proved that every finitely generated and flat (equivalently, torsion-free) $K^+$-algebra is finitely presented. The proof is ingenious, but also quite direct.
Raynaud and Gruson vastly generalized this result: if $A$ is any ring with finitely many associated primes, then every finitely generated flat $A$-algebra is finitely presented. The proof is rather involved.
Using the Raynaud–Gruson theorem, one can deduce that every topologically finitely generated $K^+$-algebra is topologically finitely presented. All it amounts to is the preceding result for $A = K^+/\pi$. This implies easily that the Tate algebra over $K$ is Noetherian, so is quite foundational in rigid geometry, though of course one can prove this corollary more directly.
I think that using the whole strength of Raynaud and Gruson to show the result for $A = K^+/\pi$ is probably overkill, especially if $K^+$ is of height one. I would like to have a direct proof of this fact. Similarly to the case of valuation rings, one can express flatness over $K^+/\pi$ in simpler terms (if $\pi=ab$ and $ax=0$, then $x=by$ for some $y$). Nevertheless, I can't make Nagata's proof work in this case.
The precise question is:

Is there a direct/simple proof of the fact that every finitely generated flat algebra over the truncated valuation ring $K^+/\pi$ is finitely presented?

